# Perl Script to sort a list of names, File name passed from a C script and then sorted list passed back

Tags: c, perl, shell, sorting, file-io

I should be able to sort a file with:
    perl -e 'print sort <>' data_file

What I'd like to do is call this script from a C script.  The C script will pass the data file name to the Perl script, and then read the sorted output.

I have that code ready to go:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
int pclose(FILE *stream);

int main(void){
    FILE *cmd = popen("myperlscript myparams", "r");
    char result[1024];

    while (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd) != NULL)
           printf("%s", result);
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

So how would I pass a list of last names in a file: data.txt from C to Perl and output the sorted list to stdout? (The Perl side of it)?

Comment: To clarify, I'll be reading the 'result' with fgets.  I just need the Perl script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace

```
FILE *cmd = popen("myperlscript myparams", "r");
```

with

```
FILE *cmd = popen("perl -e 'print sort <>' data.txt", "r");
```

I suggest you to check the result of `popen`, use this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
int pclose(FILE *stream);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *cmd;
    char result[1024];

    FILE *cmd = popen("perl -e 'print sort <>' data.txt", "r");
    if (cmd == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd)) {
        printf("%s", result);
    }
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

> Would it be possible to pass the file name in? (the data.txt) So I can
>   read different file names?

Of course, `snprintf` and the arguments of `main` are made for this ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
int pclose(FILE *stream);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char result[1024], str[128];
    FILE *cmd;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    snprintf(str, sizeof str, "perl -e 'print sort <>' %s", argv[1]);
    cmd = popen(str, "r");
    if (cmd == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(result, sizeof result, cmd)) {
        printf("%s", result);
    }
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

> I'll actually be prompting the user to enter a filename once the
>   program starts so passing in argv wouldn't work. (I believe, Very new
>   to C) I could just change this to a perlSort function, and pass
>   arguments that way, yes? To make this easier: ---Start Program
>   ---Prompt user for source data file ---Prompt user for destination data file ---Display Menu: 1 - Sort with C 2 - Sort with Perl 3 - Find
>   word with Perl

So you want to be spoonfeeded, ok, no problem, but next time make some effort yourself first or you will never learn:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
int pclose(FILE *stream);

int main(void)
{
    char result[1024], tmp[128], *p;
    FILE *cmd;

    printf("Enter a filename: ");
    fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin);
    p = strchr(tmp, '\n');
    if (p != NULL) *p = '\0';
    snprintf(result, sizeof result, "perl -e 'print sort <>' %s", tmp);
    cmd = popen(result, "r");
    if (cmd == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(result, sizeof result, cmd)) {
        printf("%s", result);
    }
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to pass the file name in? (the data.txt) So I can read different file names?

Comment: I'll actually be prompting the user to enter a filename once the program starts so passing in argv wouldn't work. (I believe, Very new to C) I could just change this to a perlSort function, and pass arguments that way, yes? To make this easier: ---Start Program ---Prompt user for source data file ---Prompt user for destination data file ---Display Menu: 1 - Sort with C 2 - Sort with Perl 3 - Find word with Perl –

Comment: Now you have two ways to launch the perl script, the menu prompting for an option is left to you as an exercise, good luck!